# QT qSharedDataPointer dynamic casting?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qshareddata

I am trying to perform the following cast and I can't find a way either in the QT documentation or online to make this dynamic cast work which has been confusing:

```
class Entity : public QSharedData
{
  public:
    typedef QExplicitlySharedDataPointer<Entity> Pointer;
    typedef QExplicitlySharedDataPointer<const Entity> ConstPointer;
...
}

class EntityExtended : public Entity
{
public:
    typedef QExplicitlySharedDataPointer<EntityExtended> Pointer;
    typedef QExplicitlySharedDataPointer<const EntityExtended> ConstPointer;
...
}



bool SomeClass::createEntity(const Entity::ConstPointer entity)
{
  auto extendedEntity = dynamic_cast<const EntityExtended::ConstPointer>(entity);
}
```

The above produces the error:

```
error C2680: 'const EntityExtended::ConstPointer': invalid target type for dynamic_cast
note: target type must be a pointer or reference to a defined class
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you can only use `dynamic_cast` on raw pointers. Even though `QExplicitlySharedDataPointer` is a class that's meant to be used like a pointer, it's not a raw pointer, so you can't use `dynamic_cast` on it.

The solution is to get the raw pointer using `QExplicitlySharedDataPointer`'s [`data()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qexplicitlyshareddatapointer.html#data) or [`constData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qexplicitlyshareddatapointer.html#constData) methods, and use `dynamic_cast` on the raw pointer instead. You can then convert it back to a `QExplicitlySharedDataPointer` by passing the raw pointer to the [`QExplicitlySharedDataPointer` constructor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qexplicitlyshareddatapointer.html#QExplicitlySharedDataPointer-1):

```cpp
bool SomeClass::createEntity(const Entity::ConstPointer entity)
{
  //Create a raw pointer to use with dynamic_cast
  const EntityExtended *rawPointer = dynamic_cast<const EntityExtended*>(entity.constData());

  //Convert the raw pointer back to a QExplicitlySharedDataPointer
  EntityExtended::ConstPointer extendedEntity = EntityExtended::ConstPointer(rawPointer);

  if(extendedEntity == nullptr){
      //*entity is not an instance of ExtendedEntity
  }
  else{
      //*entity is an instance of ExtendedEntity
  }
}
```